# SQLite3 help, saving variables into a databse

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have 2 things I needed help with:

1) I am unsure as to how I can check if a table exists in python using the  `sqlite3` library.

2) I am unsure as to how I can save variables from the program to a database. I want to be able to check if `UserDetails` exists before making the database.

I've been reading around and everyone is doing stuff differently,

Here is the section of my code that is responsible for saving the variables:

```
    connection = sqlite3.connect("UserDetails.db") 
    crsr = connection.cursor() 

    #create table
    sql_command = table_creator
    crsr.execute(sql_command)

    #insert values into table
    data_to_insert = (username, first_name, surname, age, user_salt, password_hash, date_today)
    sql_command = """INSERT INTO UserDetails VALUES ((?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), data_to_insert);"""
    crsr.execute(sql_command)

    connection.commit() #save changes
    connection.close()  #terminate connection
```

and in case you want to see  `table_creator` it looks like this:

`` table_creator = '''CREATE TABLE `UserDetails` (
    `Username` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    `Firstname` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `Surname` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `Age` INT(2) NOT NULL,
    `Salt` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `Hash` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `Date` DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`UserName`)
    );''' ``

I will appreciate and feedback or support. 
I am still learning to code, and my CompSci teacher doesnt teach us Python specifically, so what I know is self taught.

Oh and this is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call)
  File "c:/Users/Arslan/Project A2/login.py", line 99, in <module>
    save_details()
  File "c:/Users/Arslan/Project A2/login.py", line 93, in save_details
    crsr.execute(sql_command)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: data_to_insert
```

Answer (score 1):

> **How to check if a table exists or no :**

- The first way :

Use this query:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='{table_name}';
```

Modify `{table_name}` with your table to check
There are two cases :

. If the cursor equal to 0 ==> the table does not exist
  Else, the table exists

- The second way:

Use :

```
 PRAGMA table_info(table_name)
```

example:

[image]

- The third way :

Use this query :

```
select 1 from table
```

It will return the constant 1 for every row of the table if the table exists, or nothing if not.

- There are many other ways, but I listed the best in my opinion.

> **How to save variables from the program to a database:**

To insert data into sqlite3, you can use :

```
cursor.execute("insert into UserDetails values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (username, firstname, surname, age, salt, hash, date))
```

**DON'T USE (SQL injection):**

```
cursor.execute("insert into UserDetails values ('{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}')".format(username, firstname, surname, age, salt, hash, date))
```

Don't forget :

```
conn.commit()
```

Or you can use instead of it the connection as a context manager:

```
with conn:
   # then cursor.execute..
```

Comment: wow, thanks for the mini lesson. I'll try to read through it and figure out what is going on.

Comment: Hi again, I need a teeny bit of help with my select Query. ```username_finder =  ' SELECT Salt, Hash FROM UserDetails WHERE Username = ?, (username_input,) '``` it seems to not like my query. I want it to select all salts and hashes when the username matches the ```username_input```

Comment: Yeah, it is good, use : `sql_query = """ SELECT Salt, Hash FROM UserDetails WHERE Username = ?""" ` then `cursor.execute(sql_query, (username_input,))` and to see the result : `username_finder = cursor.fetchall()`  , then iterate to see the result,   `for row in username_finder: #etc `

Answer (score 0):

1) I am unsure as to how I can check if a table exists in python using the sqlite3 library.

Use [`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html):

```
table_creator = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `UserDetails` ( 
    `Username` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    `Firstname` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
...
);'''
```

2) I am unsure as to how I can save variables from the program to a database.

You can pass variables for insert with the following syntax:

```
 data_to_insert = (username, first_name, surname, age, user_salt, password_hash, date_today)
sql_command = '''INSERT INTO UserDetails VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''';
crsr.execute(sql_command, data_to_insert )
```